# Wait for command to finish in RootTools

Tags: android, root

I am using the RootTools library to execute some shell commands on my android App.

However I need to wait for the commands to finish before proceeding. The documentation shows a `waitForFinish()` method which is not available on the latest version of the library at least.

How would I accomplish a similar behaviour?

Comment: Viva, Tiago arranjas-te solução para o problema?

Comment: Sinceramente já não me lembro de como dei a volta a este problema. E entretanto já não desenvolvo para Android.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:
First you must instace the command without enabling the `handler` (with false):

```
Command command = new Command(0, false, "cat")
```

Next do something like this:

```
         RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
         while (!command.isFinished()) 
         {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

         }
```

Comment: **Please note that the 2nd parameter of Command is important!** It **must be false** otherwise a handler is created and the sleep mechanism won't work!